# ng-init is not getting the scope values initially

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am calling a function on `ng-init`. this function takes the values from the scope. 
Actually what happening is we load a page and on page load we use ng-init

```
<div ng-init="somefunction(c,d)">
</div>

$scope.somefunction = function() {
  console.log($scope.a);
}

$scope.abc = function() {
  //calling another function 
  $scope.xyz();
}
$scope.xyz = function() {
  $scope.a = "hello";
}
$scope.abc();//called on controller load
```

But I am not getting `a` in console means getting `undefined`. But after clicking on any button on page or some stuff. I got `a`. Means I am not getting this on page load.

Comment: `somefunction` is a function. Hence it has to be called with braces`()`, like, `somefunction()`.

Comment: ya i called it in same way but still same

Comment: what is `c` and `d`? They need to be defined as `$scope` variables to be able to use them

Comment: they are normal boolean parameters

Comment: and i dont thibk they should be in scope these are passes as parameter

Comment: can you post some more code? If possible, the full html with javascript. need to see if the javscript has been loaded before you call the function

Comment: issue is data is coming but not on first load

Comment: Call `$scope.abc()` inside `somefunction()` function. This should ensure that `$scope.a` is initialized before printing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using ng-init, you can directly call function in controller.
Something Like this :

```
<div></div>
$scope.a = '';
$scope.somefunction = function() {
  console.log($scope.a);
}

$scope.abc = function() {
  //calling another function 
  $scope.xyz();
}
$scope.xyz = function() {
  $scope.a = "hello";
}
$scope.abc();//called on controller load
$scope.somefunction();
```

It will simplify the process as it will execute only when everything is loaded and defined.

Comment: I tried this but $scope.watch started throwing error now and as it's client project i am not allowed to change more

Comment: Create a runnable script @AdeshKumar. So we too can see what the problem is.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please note to first define $scope.a in controller so JS hoisting can work and evaluate this variable.

Comment: calling it in controller helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call it as

```
<div ng-init="somefunction()">
</div>
```

Besides that there are chances that you might get undefined if `ng-init` is called before `$scope.abc()`

Comment: yes its surely calling ng-init before abc() that's what I am trying to resolve is there any way of calling it after abc function

Comment: You could use `pre-link` to initialise the variables if that's a directive. If it's a component then you can use `$onInit` hook. Unless you are on angularjs version < 15

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the scripts are loaded before the javascript functions. Otherwise you would get the values to be undefined.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-init="somefunction()">
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.somefunction = function() {
      $scope.abc();
      console.log($scope.a);
    }

    $scope.abc = function() {
      //calling another function 
      $scope.xyz();
    }
    $scope.xyz = function() {
      $scope.a = "hello";
    }

  });
</script>
```

Comment: i have tried this it's working but my code is big and lot of functions so not working there

Comment: can you post an [mcve] adesh? Else it would be really hard to debug the issue.